# Correlation of column vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two data sets (`D1` and `D2`) . `D1(1440,5)` and `D2(1440,5)` both have `NaN`'s at various locations.
`D1` and `D2` are 1min data(rows) for 5 days (columns). My intention is to remove the `NaN`s from each column of `D1` and `D2`, and then compute correlation coefficient R and Pvalue of each column. So I should have 5 R and P values corresponding to each column.

```
 D1 = reshape(Data1,[1440,5]); % D1 and D2 have NaNs at various locations
 D2 = reshape(Data2,[1440,5]);
 R = zeros(1,5);
 P = zeros(1,5);
 for day = 1:5
 good = isnan(D1)+isnan(D2);

 [R,P] = corrcoef((D1(good(:,1:5)==0)),(D2(good(:,1:5)==0)));
 end
```

I tried doing this by the above method, however I have been unsuccessful in getting 5 values of R and P  for each column. Is there any way to this.. Please help. any suggestions would be very helpful.Many Thanks..SS

Comment: You need to use `find(myarray == NaN)` to get all the indices that have NaN. Replace them with a value you want (probably 0), and then compute your CORR

Comment: Thanks.. But I dont want to replace it with zero as it will affect my correlation coefficient R and P value.

Comment: Replace with whatever you want or don't replace anything. You can simply find the indices using find(arr == NaN) and use those indices to remove NaNs. Similarly, you can use `find` to find indices that don't have any NaNs and use them for your work.

Comment: I am able to remove NaN's , but now I want to compute 5 values R,P for each column. Any suggestions

Comment: Also D1 and D2 both have NaN's not necessarily at same locations

Comment: Are you saying that you want to do the last line before `end` and it doesn't work for you? Also, what has it got to do with having NaNs in same position or not? You need to compute Cross Correlation of those D1 and D2. The point is to know where the peak match occurs. Having NaNs in different locations in D1 and D2 doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes.. good = isnan(D1)+ isnan(D2) gives me a logical array (1440,5) of 0's ,  1's and even 2's .. Now using this information I want to compute for every column of 'good == 0 an  R and P value ..Any suggestion

Comment: If D1 and D2 has NaN's then corrcoef doesnot work.thats why I want to remove NaN. The cross correlation xcorr is in signal processing toolbox, and I dont have that license.

Comment: @hagubear `something==NaN` doesn't work. Always use `isnan()`.

Comment: What you want is to check using `good` indices that D1 has zero or not. Why can't you use `find` in combination with good and D1? You need `D1(find(D1(good(:,1:5)) == 0))`

Comment: @Steffen       yea my bad. I realised after I saw what he did in his snippet with `good`

Comment: @ hagubear .. D1(find(D1(good(:,1:5)) == 0)) finds indices with good ==0.. But how so i get the correlation R, P column wise now..

Comment: @user3876557 When you remove the `NaN` values you are modifying the time difference between elements in the sequence and creating a totally new sequence. Say you have `[1 2 NaN NaN 3 NaN 4]`, by removing `NaN` values you get `[1 2 3 4]`, In original signal 2 and 3 were 3 samples apart but in the result they are only 1 sample apart. So if you calculate correlation it will not make sense. Depending on properties of the signals you might be able to interpolate values or have your own correlation routine that ignores `NaN`s.